# Не могу зайти в localhost/xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

Установил XAMPP. Вроде бы, все нормально, но, вот, при переходе по ссылке http://localhost/xampp/ получается такое вот:
Переустанавливал версии (5, 7.1, 7.0, 7,2), порты менял. В чем проблема? [image: Пробую войти]

Comment: Скорее всего нет файлов и конечно же самого index файла

Answer (score 0):

В XAMPP входит Apache2, здесь для домена localhost указана директория в которой нету никаких файлов. А так все работает так как надо, возможно неверно указана директория для localhost, так как должна быть указана директория в которой лежыт index.php от XAMPP

На Windows или на Linux было установлено XAMPP? Нужно искать как создавать хост и указывать для него директорию. А когда будет ясно как делать это тогда можно будет увидеть что именно с конфигурациями для localhost.

Comment: На Windows установлено

Comment: httpd-vhosts.conf что в этом файле? Его можно найти  поиском в установленом XAMPP

Comment: Два раза повторяется это: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

Comment: DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com" 
обрати внимание на эту директорию что в ней?

Comment: httpd-vhosts.conf в этом файле указано что для 
ServerName dummy-host2.example.com 
будет назначена директория 
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"

Если открыть такой домен в браузере что будет dummy-host2.example.com?

Comment: Так же что в файле C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts?
или файл hosts может находиться в другом месте

Comment: Там правила Unchecky и активация программы одной в 127.0.0.1 прописана, чтобы блокировать доступ к интернету. Последнее, как я понимаю, оно?